# How to add GFM task lists in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown, kramdown

GFM supports Task lists:

https://github.com/blog/1375-task-lists-in-gfm-issues-pulls-comments

how do I use this in Jekyll pages? In my site's `_config.yml`

```
# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  hard_wrap: false
```

This works for most other GFM constructs. but not with Task Lists.

Example markdown:

```
#### Checklist for Aggregations
- [ ] Always add `max(x)` in the group for size of buckets needed. When data is distributed across multiple content nodes this result can be inaccurate. To increase accuracy we need to use `precision(x)` as well to tune accuracy as we need.
```

Expected:

[image]

Reality:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of kramdown are you using? GFM task lists are supported as of [1.16.0](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/news.html#kramdown-1160-released) (with a bugfix released in [1.16.1](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/news.html#kramdown-1161-released)). To eliminate the bulleted list, [`list-style-type: none` is necessary](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/pull/442#issue-242886287).

On my system, the following test file

```
---
---

- [ ] Unchecked
- [x] Checked
{: style='list-style-type: none'}
```

generates the expected

[image: GFM task list]

using kramdown 1.16.2 and Jekyll 3.6.2. If your kramdown is earlier than 1.16.1, you should be able to simply

```
$ gem update kramdown
```

to gain the functionality.

Comment: Note that, as of 5th Jan 2018 the version of Kramdown used on GitHub Pages is `1.14.0` so this does not yet work for GitHub pages.